# Having single parent list and multiple (different) child lists using lookUp column

Tags: list-view-web-part

My name is George and I am new to Sharepoint.
I started using Sharepoint 2013 foundation and I want to make a relation between a parent list which has a lookup column (something like 'Type') and more than three child lists, different lists, which have the column that specify the 'Type'.
How could i make this kind of relation? I read about one to one relation by adding a web part - the child list, but what happens when i have more than one child list? is there anyone who can help me on this issue?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

At site collection level, create a site lookup column(Say, TestColumnX) that refers to your list Say "TestListA" and point to the title field.

On your child site, go to you desired list settings and add a new column based from an existing one. Pick the one you just created.